# Regex email : number + format of email in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby, model-view-controller

I have a field email in my database also call emails that should have this format : `123456789@pac.gmail.com` where `123456789` should be numbers and a length of 9.

In my model, I tried to format this for my user with the following code :

```
class Email < ApplicationRecord
    EMAIL_PATTERN = /^[0-9]+/@pac.gmail.com
    LENGTH = 9
    validates :email, presence: true, format: EMAIL_PATTERN, length: LENGTH
end
```

But with that I have an error `unexpected tIVAR, expecting end` but I don't get why should I have a `END` in my code as I don't start any loop or something, 
Is anyone knows how to format the email in the right way and why I have this kind of error ?

Comment: Check the placement of your regex delimiters.

Comment: `/^[0-9]+#{Regexp.escape('@pac.gmail.com')}$/`, or manually escape your regex special chars `/^[0-9]+@pac\.gmail\.com$/`. Note that `^` and `$` always match the start and end of a line in Ruby. Use `\A` and `\z` to match the start and end of a string. Currently your regex is `/^[0-9]+/` followed by an instance variable `@pac` which Ruby is not expecting at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to separately check the length; you can do that from within your regex. If I'm understanding correctly, you want to make sure there are 9 digits followed by `@pac.gmail.com`. You can do it like this:

```rb
class Email < ApplicationRecord
  EMAIL_PATTERN = /\A[0-9]{9}@pac.gmail.com\z/
  validates :email, presence: true, format: EMAIL_PATTERN
end
```